# Code to represent circuits

Tags: feature-request

I'm not happy uploading screenshots everytime I have a question about a circuit. Besides that, SE itself does not host the images used in the posts, which might lead to broken links in the future.

Can we have a code that generates a circuit after compilation? Analogous to MathJax in math.SE in order to type formulas.

It can be similar to the syntax of current simulation programs, for example, the code

```
$
V1 N001 0 1
R1 N001 0 100
$
```

would display a circuit having a 1 V DC supply connected to a 100 Ohm resistor and showing a ground connection.

Comment: A net list is not a schematic.  Layout and visual presentation are important aspects of schematics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, but this is unlikely to happen

1. It's something new and (somewhat) confusing to use. It does not lower any barriers to add schematics.
2. We already have a built-in schematic editor, CircuitLab
3. Using software to make a human-readable schematic is *hard*. Sure, two components are easy, but 5-10 can be impossible.
4. Such software does not exist (to my knowledge). StackExchange doesn't develop MathJax, CircuitLab, or the syntax highlighting, and they probably wouldn't develop this.
5. StackExchange has an agreement with imgur to host images. As long as you upload the file directly, (which is really easy) the image will be there as long as necessary.

Comment: I didn't know any of these. I must say, well done!